# Can I somehow preserve values of local macros in Stata after the completion of the do-file?

Tags: local, stata

Whenever I add new lies to the code (e.g. when computing a different estimate) I do not want to rerun the whole do-file again. However, I often need the values of certain local macros that were generated during the previous run of the do-file.

Is there a way to keep those values? Or I should switch to using more globals instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globals are by no means the only alternative.

First, consider using scalars. A scalar with a permanent name will survive beyond the end of a do-file.

Second, consider converting your do-file to a program and learning about saved results.

Third, you can always consider putting results in a new variable; it's just that it is usually bad style and wasteful on storage.

At a guess, the first is likely to be the most useful for you. Many Stata users are happy to use do-files with many dataset-specific statements. Jumping to writing fully-fledged and more general programs is a big jump and not (at first) trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use `global`.

But note that you need to be careful with `global` for the exact reason you are using it: the macro remains in memory until you exit that instance of Stata, or until you reset it within the code.

Some people have very strong feelings about not using `global` ever (see pp5 and continuing here: http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/matthew.gentzkow/research/ra_manual_coding.pdf). Once you learn their properties, and to not incur the small number of problems they can potentially cause, you should be fine.